# Asynchronously and recursively crawl links Javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, asynchronous

I am making a Blog using [Notion](https://www.notion.so/) as a content management system. There is an unofficial API provided by [notion-api-js](https://github.com/cstrnt/notion-api), with a  function `getPagesByIndexId(pageId)` that returns a page's content, its subpages' contents, and, its parent's contents. So, an array of objects is returned, looking like:

```
[
  { moreStuff: ..., 
    Attributes: { slug: "home page slug", id: "home page id", moreStuff... },
  },
  { moreStuff: ..., Attributes: { slug: "parent to homepage", id: "homepage's parent id", moreStuff: ... }
  { moreStuff: ..., Attributes: { slug: "sub page slug 0", id: "sub page id 0", moreStuff: ... } },
  { moreStuff: ..., Attributes: { slug: "sub page slug 1", id: "sub page id 1", moreStuff: ... } },
];
```

I want to build a tree that is created by recursively looping through the given id and the ids that `getPagesByIndexId(given id)` return to extract all slugs and ids. The function stops recursing when `getPagesByIndexId(id)` returns objects with ids already crawled through.

I use a `crawledIdsList` array to keep track of ids already crawled through, fetchPage is the same as `getPagesByIndex`, and I use flatmap to ignore empty `[]`s passed by from the map function. Thanks in advance! To run this locally on node, the dependency required is `npm i notion-api-js`

The tree structure of the page I provided the ID with (I provided the id to the "Dev" page in `homePageId`) looks like:

[image: page hierarchy]

My current code follows. It hits the "end" and returns successfully, but it is returning many pages a lot more than once.

```
const Notion = require("notion-api-js").default;
const token_v2 = "543f8f8529f361ab34596f5be9bc972b96ab8d8dc9e6e41546c05751b51a18a6c7d40b689d80794babae3a91aeb5dd5e47c34edb724cc356ceceacf3a8061158bfab92e68b7614516a0699295990"
const notion = new Notion({
  token: token_v2,
});

const fetchPage = (id) => {
  return notion.getPagesByIndexId(id);
};

const homePageId = "3be663ea-90ce-4c45-b04e-41161b992dda" 
var crawledIdsList = [];
buildTree(tree={}, homePageId).then(tree => {console.log(tree)}) 
function buildTree(tree, id) {
  return fetchPage(id).then((pages) => {
    tree.subpages = [];
    tree.slug = pages[0].Attributes.slug;
    tree.id = id;
    crawledIdsList.push(id);
    return Promise.all(
      pages.flatMap((page) => {
        var currentCrawlId = page.Attributes.id;
        if (crawledIdsList.indexOf(currentCrawlId) === -1) {
          // executes code block if currentCrawlId is not used in fetchPage(id) yet
          crawledIdsList.push(currentCrawlId);
          return buildTree({}, currentCrawlId).then((futureData) => {
            tree.subpages.push(futureData);
            return tree;
          });
        } else {
          if (crawledIdsList.indexOf(id) >= 0) {
            return [];
          }
          return tree; // end case. futureData passed to earlier calls is tree, which looks like {subpages: [], slug: someSlug, id: someId}
        }
      })
    )
  });
}
```

Comment: token_v2 is my personal token, not safe for me, but it is a playground account I am using, will remove once problem solved

Comment: I think I am handling the crawledIdsList weirdly, wrapping my head around it rn